gs1 QR printing issue
I have an issue when printing a GS1 datamatrix barcode (= QR code) using ZPL codes on a zebra printer. My code is:
^XA^
FS
^FT270,280^BXN,9,200,0,0,1,_,1
^FD(95)KMAHAMODE(96)toyota1560Fc12(97)lan^
FS
^FT270,580^BXN,9,200,0,0,1,_,1
^FD_195kmahamode_196toyota1560Fc12_197lan^
FS^CF0,30^PQ1^XZ

The QR code contains the login credential to log in an app on an hand held scanner.
When I scan a QR code that was generated by the Labelary site or Z designer, I am able to log in, but when I scan the exact same code, printed with Zebra printer version 6.7, the QR code is not recognized.
Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

I cleaned up your question a bit. If anything is obviously wrong, please correct it. I removed the line: "tried different settings", because it didn't add anything without actually specifying what you tried. Have you visually compared the three results you got? Anything different? You could add the output of your printer as a photo to your question, so we can see what got printed.

Hi thanks  for the reply actually  the issue was that the printer  was not  compatible  with gs1 datamatrix font used a later version printing  was OK.
